# getting a error message from my php

Tags: php

I have created a page on my site with the surfix .php {after taking a crash course in php}
and I am getting this error message:

> Warning: include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server
>   configuration by allow_url_include=0 in
>   /home/u259153114/public_html/php_site/about.php on line 12 Warning:
>   include(http://musiccafefriends.neq3.com/php_site/header.php): failed
>   to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in
>   /home/u259153114/public_html/php_site/about.php on line 12 Warning:
>   include(): Failed opening
>   'http://musiccafefriends.neq3.com/php_site/header.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php') in
>   /home/u259153114/public_html/php_site/about.php on line 12 Warning:
>   include(/php_site/includes/nav.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in /home/u259153114/public_html/php_site/about.php
>   on line 13 Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   '/php_site/includes/nav.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php') in
>   /home/u259153114/public_html/php_site/about.php on line 13

so now what I done wrong I love web design and learning new things but this is stressing me out now lol yes I can see it is saying there that these files or directories do not exist but trust me they do all directories and files are in there it seems to me that for some reason the neq3 server is blocking my coding any ideas

Answer (score 2):

This message is rather self explanatory:

```
include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0
```

means you are trying to include remote file (which is very, very bad idea), like:

```
include('http://...../file.php');
```

but (usually for security reasons) this feature is disabled on this server. I'd recommend copy the remote file and include it locally.

Comment: serious your saying as simple as that I missed some stupid reverse link thing so the server trying to remote my laptop instead of the files on the server?

Comment: do you still not understand meaning of warning you quoted?

Comment: think so yes I am just going in now to look at my codes just had to deal with my baby haha

Comment: I think this is what you was talking about:

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to include a remote file in your script. Instead of doing that, you could just copy the contents of the external file, put it in a file on **your** server and then include it.

Comment: </head>
 <body>
<?php include('http://musiccafefriends.neq3.com/php_site/header.php'); ?>
<?php include('/php_site/includes/nav.php'); ?>
<div id="content">

Comment: Why did you paste that here?

Answer (score 1):

As Orangepill said, the default setting for allow_url_include is to disable it.

Unless I am mistaken, though, it looks like the file you are trying to include is actually on the same server (they both seem to be in a directory called php_site). If that's the case, you can change your include from:

```
include('http://musiccafefriends.neq3.com/php_site/header.php');
```

to:

```
include('header.php');
```

If they're not hosted on the same server, your best bet is to move the file you want to include onto the server you want to include it on.

`allow_url_include` is disabled by default to prevent cross-site scripting, because the code will be evaluated at the other end before it is included on your end, meaning nasty stuff can be injected and run on your server.

As for your second problem:

```
Failed opening '/php_site/includes/nav.php'
```

The slash `/` at the beginning of the path makes it an "absolute path", so PHP is looking for the file at the root of your filesystem and not finding it. You are looking for a file called 'nav.php' in a folder called 'includes' under the current one. If you change your include to `include('includes/nav.php')`, it should work.

Comment: it was a lot more simple than any of us could of realised when I was creating these documents such as *** index.php ; about.php ; header.php and so on I thought I would be cleaver and faster to use a notepad hand code my doc then save them as php files however this doesn't work always and you get a file with the extension .php.txt so of course when the server is searching for header.php or sidebar.php it cant find it omg what a dumb ass I am thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

As the error states your host has the 'allow_url_include` set to false (the default). This is to avoid cross site script inclusion.

Your options here are to either change the allow_url_include directive to 1 or to copy the asset to the local machine and included it via a file system reference.

Comment: I wish I could say that has fixed it but it has not I have tried re loading the files into the root directory instead of the directory /php_site and I change the file paths as you suggested however I am still getting these error messages

Comment: ok this is my official diagnostic of my ERROR that you so kindly tried to help me with